# Set-Cookie not working in IE

Tags: html, cookies, php4, setcookie

I am using the Set-Cookie function ..it works fine in chrome and firefox.

It sets the cookie and I can see it in firebug.

But for some reason it is not setting the cookie in I.E

Can anyone verify if my syntax is correct or if I am doing something wrong?

```
    function generateSession($cookieName="wic_secure_sess", $idTag="", $numChars=32, $expireSeconds=0, $path=null, $domain=null, $secure=2) {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])) {
            $sessId = $idTag;
            for ($i=0; $i<$numChars; $i++) {
                srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
                $randomType=rand(1, 3);
                srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
                switch ($randomType) {
                case 1:
                    $sessId.=chr(rand(65, 90));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $sessId.=chr(rand(97, 122));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $sessId.=rand(0, 9);
                    break;
                }
            }

        $expires = str_replace('+0000', 'GMT', gmdate('r', strtotime('+30 days')));
            if ($expireSeconds != 0) {
                $expireSeconds = time()+$expireSeconds;
            }

            if (livecheck() || stagecheck()) {
            header( "Set-Cookie:". $cookieName."=".$sessId."; expires=".$expires."; path=".$path.";HttpOnly;secure;");

            }
            else {



                     header( "Set-Cookie:". $cookieName."=".$sessId.";               expires=".$expires."; path=".$path.";HttpOnly");

            }   



        } else {
            $sessId = $_COOKIE[$cookieName];
        }
        return $sessId;
    }
?>
I dont want to use setcookie() because i am running php4 version since php4 does not support httponly in the setcookie() function
```

EDIT: the php setcookie() function works perfectly fine in IE. When i use header() thats creating the problem.

```
setcookie($cookieName, $sessId, $expireSeconds, $path, $domain, $secure);
```

Here is the call to my function:

```
generateSession( "my_sess", "", 20, 14400, "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a [P3P privacy policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/P3P/). This policy format is only accepted by Internet Explorer these days, but helps overcome cookie blocking from the browser privacy policy. There are two parts to a P3P privacy policy: policy file and compact policy header. The compact policy header is often sufficient for most applications and the least effort to implement. The different categories of P3P have compact codes for brevity in the header, e.g. navigation => NAV. At a minimum, I would start with the interactive (INT), navigation (NAV), and uniqueid (UNI) codes for the compact policy.

In Grails/Java, here is an example of how to pass back the header:

```
response.setHeader("P3P", "CP='INT NAV UNI'");
```